# The Legendary Ludwig "Hot Mix" of Led Zeppelin II

Tags: led-zeppelin

Surprised this hasn't been asked yet, but what is the difference between a copy of Zep II with just "RL" in the deadwax on both sides, "RL SS" on one side with just "RL" on the other, and "RL SS" on both sides?  Are any of the above combinations *not* considered a "Ludwig Hot Mix"?  Which, if any, came out first?  Are there known sonic differences between the three?

Comment: Related https://www.wired.com/2015/03/hot-stampers/ about half way down the page

Comment: Discogs is my usual resource for this kind of thing, see the list [here](https://www.discogs.com/master/4170-Led-Zeppelin-Led-Zeppelin-II). Based on track content, doesn't look to be different, but clearly differences in appearance and prob also packaging.